# Month Wise data merge

Tags: r

Lets say I have three different data sets and for understanding sake lets name them A, B, C.

A is let's say consumers month wise Medical expense data.
[image: A]

B is consumers month wise expenditure for fuel.
[image: B]

C is consumers month wise expenditure for food.
[image: C]

The second column in each dataset is consumer ID. Also, this is sample data, hence ignore NAs

```
data <-dcast(A, ConsumerID +Month ~Expenses)
```

I have used `dcast` to first convert data in wide format from long format for A, B, C

I want to create a new data set which will include consumer id along with monthly expense. Here monthly expense should be sum of fuel + food + medical for that particular month. I have tried converting the data in long format from wide format and then do the data merge but it is not helping much.

Is there any other efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, please supply your input data as the output from `dput()` rather than as images: we can't easily create objects to test our suggestions from images.

Answer (score -1):

If the columns are exactly the same in all three datasets, you can just concatenate them and aggregate them by user:

```
newdata = cbind(A,B,C)
data.summary = aggregate(newdata,by=list(newdata$ID),FUN=sum,na.rm=T)
```

You will then get a new data.frame that contains the sum of values for each ID and month.

Comment: The number of rows is no problem. They can be of different length. They only need the exact same columns for this syntax to work.